# AngularJS - don't know how to implement this function with a ng-repeat, logic-issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, and I'm stuck on an implementation.

I'm going and try to be as clear as possible, I can't just post a jsFiddle as the project is pretty big with lots of functions and API calls, but any way my question is about logic, I know what I need to do, but I don't know how you can do it in AngularJS.

A user can assign a task to a specific day, he has a calendar, and each day has a dropdown list with all the available tasks. He can simply select one and that's it, everything works.

But now I'm implementing something more, the user can add up to 2 tasks, one in the morning and one in the afternoon.

Let's see the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in (d.assignment.tasks || [null]) track by $index">
```

this is the container of a single day, where the dropdown will be shown.
So basically, if no tasks are added or only one is added, it will show a simple dropdown in the `div`.

But when you click on a specific button (which is placed as the first element of the dropdown list), this `ng-click` fires:

```
<ul>
<li ng-click="addTask(p.person.id, d.date, 'afternoon', null)> SPLIT ME </li>
```

this function is used to add tasks, and you can select as argument: `'morning'`, `'afternoon'`, `'both'`

By doing this, I'm adding a "empty" task (where the 'null' is, we pass as argument the task selected) to the afternoon. So the container DIV above, now loops over 2 tasks, and this makes another dropdown menu appear in the same DIV.

All working as intended so far. Now, after the first `<li>` item of the dropdown, which has the `ng-click` mentioned above, we have a `ng-repeat` that loops over all the tasks available:

```
 <li ng-repeat="k in $scope.tasks" ng-click="addAssignment(p.person.id, d.date, 'both', k)">{{k.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

so here we show all the tasks, and when the user clicks on one, we use the same function as above, and add the task to 'both'.

So if we don't consider the splitting option, everything works, the user selects a single task and that task is passed in the function and added to the whole day.

**Now the problem is**, the user decides to split the day, so first he clicks on the split button, and a second dropdown appears.

The problem as you can see, is that the second dropdown, will have the same `<li>` elements looped, so that means the same ng-click, and you can see that the ng-click has 'both' as argument, so when he selects something from the second dropdown, we go back to square 1, only one DIV showed because the last task got added on the whole day.

What I need is, if the user splits the day, the first dropdown will use as argument of the `ng-click` `'morning'`, and for the second dropdown it will use `'afternoon'`.

Then if the user clicks again on the split button, depending from **where** he clicked (First dropdown or second?), the task that was selected in that dropdown, now will be the main task for the whole day (so argument is 'both').

My first idea was to make a function to use as argument for the `'both'`, `'morning'`, `'afternoon'`, so something like:

```
ng-click="addTask(p.person.id, d.date, function(), k)"
```

but I'm stuck.

**The main problem is**, I don't know with the `ng-repeat`, when a new object gets created, so now we have 2 divs, how can I use a specific `ng-click` with a DIV and another with the second DIV.

Finally, if all of this is not clear, I'm going to try and explain it with words:

`ng-repeat` loops over 1 object, all fine, we use my `addTask()` function with 'both'.

`ng-repeat` now loops over 2 objects, I need that `addTask()` takes 'morning' for the first object and 'afternoon' for the second object.

Hope I was clear enough, sorry for the confusion!

**EDIT:**

I might have found a solution myself, I'm working on something like this:

```
    <li ng-if="split" ng-repeat="k in $scope.tasks" 
ng-click="$parent.$parent.$first && addTask(p.person.id, d.date, 'morning', k);
 $parent.$parent.$last && addTask(p.person.id, d.date, 'afternoon', k)">
{{k.name}}</li>

    <li ng-if="!split" ng-repeat="k in $scope.tasks" 
ng-click="$parent.$parent.$first && addTask(p.person.id, d.date, 'both', k)">
{{k.name}}test</li>
```

so basically I have 2 `<li>` items, and with an ng-if I only show one of them, depending if the split button has been activated or not.

Then I found out you can use `$parent.$parent.$first` to access parent ng-repeats, so thanks to that inside an ng-click, I can trigger 2 different function for 2 different elements of the parent ng-repeat,

going to do some more tests, but at first glance it seems to work!!

any inputs on better solutions are more then welcome

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that I can directly answer your question, but I've tried to understand the issue you are facing so I have described my answer below as well in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NH7ojE1ohU9CHgXlZF0t?p=preview) for your reference. Please check and post your response.

**Templates:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="sdl in schedules track by $index">
  <li ng-repeat="tm in tasks[sdl.value]" ng-click="addTask(tm)">{{tm}}</li>
  <button type="button" ng-if="sdl.value!='Both'" name="tm" ng-click="splitDay($index);">SPLIT ME</button>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.tasks = {
    Morning: ['Morning'],
    Afternoon: ['Afternoon'],
    Both: ['Morning', 'Afternoon']
  };
  $scope.schedules=[{
    name: 'One',
    value: 'Morning'
  },{
    name: 'Two',
    value: 'Afternoon'
  },{
    name: 'Three',
    value: 'Both'
  },{
    name: 'Four',
    value: 'Morning'
  },{
    name: 'Five',
    value: 'Both'
  }];
  $scope.addTask=function(tasks){
    console.log(tasks);
  };
  $scope.splitDay=function(index){
    $scope.schedules[index].value='Both';
  };
```

Comment: going to check your answer, but I edited my main post at the same time, I think I found a working solution! check my latest edit, maybe you'll also understand better the issue, so far it seems to be working!!!